# Foxpro Database Programming Libary for Linux

Tags: linux, database, c++, c

I'm in the process of migrating a large windows legacy application written in Delphi using the Apollo Database Drivers which stores it's data in foxpro database files (dbf/cdx/fpt).

The current plan is to move all the UI to a web based system and moving all the data to Postgres.

In the meantime, it would be helpful if some of the batch processes that run on the server could update the foxpro files directly.

Can anyone suggest a C/C++ programming library for Linux (either open source or commercial) that can do that? The last one I was familiar with was Codebase from Sequiter Software, but they've gone out of business.

-- Leon

Comment: Hello, Leon, welcome aboard :-) Just to be clear – I *think* that you are looking for a one off conversion of the existing database, and that we don’t actually need to mention Delphi, just recommend a standalone databse format conversion tool (export from Foxpr, import ot Postgres). Is that correct?

Comment: Actually no - I could manage a one off conversion.  About 15 years ago I was able to write a generic export utility that would export the foxpro data to xml, which I could then use to update a postgres database.

I'm currently looking for a programming library that would allow me to update the  foxpro database files from a linux application.  Since my original post I've found the source code for last Codebase release mentioned above and I'm attempting to get it recompiled and tested on Linux.